# Application crahes when loading initially

Tags: iphone

We have the loaded the app in the itunes but it got rejected because of following issues...

How to overcome the crashing reports while loading initially

This is the message from apple's site...
"Here is how we found this crash:  1) Launch application while connected to cellular or WiFi network connection. 2) Tap on the Find My Location button. 3) Application produces a crash."

can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: share the related code! have you tried it yourself?

Comment: This belongs on clairvoyant.com. :)  Seriously though, you need to provide, at least, crash details (error code, exception information, backtrace, whatever). If you don't have this data, you'll have to reproduce the crash yourself and gather this data. It's a common starting point when debugging a crash. (Did I really have to write this?)

Comment: Launched the app... Thanks a lot for he;ping me..

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed Apple's advice at all and tried to reproduce the crash? Do that, and check all the methods related to the Find My Location Button. Good things to look for - double releases, nil objects, infinite loops, that you're targeting the right iOS etc. Beyond stating the obvious, no one here can help you until you help us!